# Solenoid with conductive fabric

Tags: electromagnetism

So you know how you can create an electromagnet by winding copper into a solenoid around a metal nail and sending current through it?

Is it possible to do this with conductive thread instead of copper?

Comment: If the conductive thread is just strands of bare metal, not coated with any insulation, then it won't be a good choice for magnet winding because the turns will short-circuit. Maybe consider trying a very fine gauge of *magnet wire*, since it's already got suitable enamel coating to prevent shorts, and is very fine and supple like a thread.

Comment: Yes, but poorly. Conductive thread is likely to have such a high resistance that the current will be weak and you won't even be able to feel the magnetic force (though a compass might detect it).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to make an electromagnet with anything that conducts electricity.

Copper tends to be higher conductivity than thread, so needs less power.